# If $|A \cup B \cup C | = |A| + |B| + |C|$, then $A, B$, and $C$ must be pairwise disjoint

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let A, B, and C be finite sets. Prove or disprove:

If $|A \cup B \cup C | = |A| + |B| + |C|$, then $A, B$, and $C$ must be pairwise disjoint.

---

I started with inclusion-exclusion formula

$$|A \cup B \cup C | = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C| - |B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C|$$

Hypothesis says if $|A \cup B \cup C | = |A| + |B| + |C|$, then expression $|A \cap B \cap C|  - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C| - |B \cap C| $, must be equal to zero. So, we have

$$ |A \cap B \cap C|  - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C| - |B \cap C|  = 0$$
$$ |A \cap B \cap C|  = |A \cap B| + |A \cap C| + |B \cap C| \tag{1}$$

Now, I am not sure how finish this proof. I found two ways, but I do not know if are correct.

#### First way

If  $x \in |A \cap B \cap C|$, then $x \in |A \cap B| \wedge x\in |A \cap C| \wedge x \in |B \cap C|$.

So if we count the cardinality of $|A \cap B \cap C|  = |A \cap B| + |A \cap C| + |B \cap C|$, then if $x \in |A \cap B \cap C|$ then $x$ is counted once but on RHS $x$ is counted three times. Thus the equation is true if $A = B = C = \emptyset$.

Therefore $A, B,$ and $C$ are pairwise disjoint.

#### Second way

From inclusion-exclusion formula, I know $$|A \cap B \cap C| = - |A| - |B| - |C| + |A \cap B| + |A \cap C| + |B \cap C| - |A \cup B \cup C |$$
I substitute in equation (1)
$$ -|A| - |B| - |C| + |A \cap B| + |A \cap C| + |B \cap C| - |A \cup B \cup C | = |A \cap B| + |A \cap C| + |B \cap C|$$
The expression $|A \cap B| + |A \cap C| + |B \cap C|$ cancels out.
$$ |A| + |B| + |C| + |A \cup B \cup C | = 0$$

And this equation is true if $A = B = C = \emptyset$.
Therefore $A, B,$ and $C$ are pairwise disjoint.

---

My question is which way is correct and better or if there is a different method to prove the proposition. Thank you. (I am self-studying student, who is reading a  textbook about discrete mathematics).

Comment: The first approach is incomplete.  You did not consider the case where $A\cap B\cap C$ is empty, whilst $A\cap B$ is not.

Comment: The second approach is incorrect.  You got a wrong formula for the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion and should at the end simply obtain $|A\cup B\cup C|-|A|-|B|-|C|=0$ (so, you proved nothing here).  See answers below for correct approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your first way is correct unless $A \cap B \cap C=\emptyset.$
- The equation in your second way has to be corrected as $$|A \cap B \cap C| = - |A| - |B| - |C| + |A \cap B| + |A \cap C| + |B \cap C| + |A \cup B \cup C |$$ and substituting this leads to a nothing (as you use the same equation twice).

This is how I would answer this question (using inclusion-exclusion principal):
$A \cap B \cap C\subset A \cap B$ and therefore $|A \cap B \cap C|  \le |A \cap B|, |A \cap C|, |B \cap C|.$
Then we have 
$$3|A \cap B \cap C|  \le |A \cap B| + |A \cap C| + |B \cap C|.$$ Now combining this with what you have already found $$|A \cap B \cap C|  = |A \cap B| + |A \cap C| + |B \cap C|,$$ we can say $$|A \cap B| =|A \cap C| = |B \cap C|=|A \cap B \cap C|=0 .$$

Comment: Could you comment on the asker's work?

Comment: @Bumblebee In which case is first way correct unless $A \cap B \cap C = \emptyset$? So, we substitute and get $3(|A \cap B| + |A \cap C| + |B \cap C| ) \leq |A \cap B| + |A \cap C| + |B \cap C|$ and this is have only one solution if $|A \cap B| = |A \cap C| = |B \cap C| = 0$, then $|A \cap B \cap C| = 0$. Therefore A,B, and C are pairwise dosjoint. Am I correct?

Comment: @Kapur: If $A \cap B \cap C = \emptyset,$ then you can not take an element $x$ from that. Therefore you have to consider that possibility separately.

Comment: @Bumblebee: So I have to suppose $x \in A$, then $x \in B$, then $x \in C$, then $x \in A \cap B$  and so on, until $x \in A \cap B \cap C$ , together 8 possibilities? I know, this approach is not good, but i want find my mistake.

Comment: You don't need to consider cases here. If $A \cap B \cap C = \emptyset$ then your first equation immediately give you $|A \cap B| + |A \cap C| + |B \cap C|=0$ which proves the pairwise disjointedness.

Comment: @Bumblebee Ok, and if $A \cap B \cap C \neq \emptyset$, then the equation is false (as I proven). Then proof is completed?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $A$, $B$, $C$ are not pairwise disjoint.  Then the intersection of two of them, wlog $A$ and $B$, is nonempty.  Now $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B| < |A| + |B|$,
and $|A \cup B \cup C| \le |A \cup B| + |C| <  |A| + |B| + |C|$.

Comment: Could you comment also in your answer on the asker's work in the question?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank you. I know about contradiction a litle bit, but in the book what I'm reading is this topic after this example. So i prefer directly proof, but i get it, and it's easier than directly proof.